# Is there a way to dynamically change css attributes without defined amount of possible changes

Tags: html, css, angular

In my project, I want to let the user choose the color of the software. For now, the choices are defined, BUT in the future, I want to make a color picker, so the possibilities will be ... large.

I have tried to use `[style.background-color]` which works great for attributes that are not used on "selector made" elements. Some of my styled elements, with colors that might change, are `:after`, `:before`, `:hover` elements, so `[style.attribute]` doesn't work on them.

I have tried to use `[attr.data-background-color]` and then in my css file, using it like follow

```css
[data-background-color].element:after{
  ...
  content: attr(data-background-color);
  background-color: attr(data-background-color);
  ...
}
```

I have added the `data-background-color` to content to see if it was at least changed and for content it works great. Of course I know this is the normal behavior as explained in the documentation, only `content` is supported.

I have also tried to use variables and pass it through `[ngStyle]` like this `[ngStyle]="{'--bg: backgroundColor'}"` but nothing happened. Maybe I don't really know how to use it in Angular and so to pass value created in `ts` file.

Finally, how those three methods works are exactly what I need.

I would like to have something else than defining all the classes and use `[ngClass]` to set the right color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) which you can define on the `:root`, or on any element. When used the element that uses the var will traverse up the DOM using the first variable that matches the one used. These then can be used on any element in your component.

```js
// Place this method in an angular service
function changeColor(color) {
  const root = document.documentElement;
  
  root.style.setProperty('--background', color);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background: red;
}

div {
  --background: red;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background);
}

span {
  background-color: var(--background);
}

/* You can also utilize the vars in components as well */
/* The below is an example of a component, it doesn't work on stackoverflow though */
:host {
  my-component {
    background-color: var(--background);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeColor('red')">Red</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('green')">Green</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue')">Blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('#800080')">Purple</button>


<!-- Note here how the same var is also defined on the div -->
<!-- This var will be used on the span instead of the one defined in the root -->
<div>
  <span>
    Hello World
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't had in mind that I had to initiate the variable ... I have combined it with `[style.--background]` to be able to update the value as I wanted, by adding the dynamic value in the template. Thanks